# How to assign a value from a DataRow

Tags: c#, ado.net, datarow

I have the following code that takes a DataSet and a currenYear as arguments. The code is supposed to look into the GrowthTarget DataTable, select a rows that meets the criteria in the Select property, then assign it to a foundRows array.

The next part is simply to get the value of the second column in the returned row and assign it to YearGrowthTarget. Problem is when I run it debug mode and put a break point on the line that does this assignment, the “step into” simply exits the method altogether and messes up data that is supposed to display on the main form.
I thought that at least the return YearGrowthTarget should be executed but NO, the system feels like superman and goes on to load the main form.

By the way, the code ought to run before the main form displays its data.
Can anyone please tell what I’m doing wrong?

```
private static int NewYearFreshInstallationGrowthTarget(DataSet ds, int currentYear)
    {
        int YearGrowthTarget = 0;

        DataRow[] foundRows = ds.Tables["GrowthTarget"].Select(
                "GrowthTargetYear = " + currentYear);
        if (foundRows.Length == 0)
        {
            // There are no entries for current year, return 0.
            //TODO: Update statusLabel within original method that called
            //this methos: ComputeNetGrowth method.
        }
        else if (foundRows.Length == 1)
        {
            // There is an entry for current year so return target.
            YearGrowthTarget = (int)(foundRows[0].ItemArray[1]);
        }

        return YearGrowthTarget;
    }
```

Comment: Did you getting any error or compiler just misses to execute this function. Your scenario is not clear !!!

Comment: Nope, no errors. This method is a helper method. The problem is  at the line where I make the assignment from the DataRow to the YearGrowthTarget variable, all the methods that are involved are exited and the main form loads with messed up data.

Comment: which line ?? and what is the problem ?

Comment: The statement that is supposed to execute within the eise if code block does not execute, then all the methods involved stops execution altogether. The program does not even get to the return YearGrowthTarget line before all the methods are exited.

Comment: Found the problem. The type of the column where the value I needed was a string, changing it to an Int32 did the trick. Thanks for trying @Rajeev